# .htaccess file configuration for Windows localhost

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uwamp

how substitute content from "work1/public" subdirectories when you enter aaa.aaa/work1 ?

I tested

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) /work1/public/
```

But it only works when you are asking for something

> http://aaa.aaa/work1/foo
>
> http://aaa.aaa/work1/bar

if nothing is entered

> http://aaa.aaa/work1

rule does not work :-(

can anyone help me ?

Thank you very much

```
aaa.aaa === localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in your `/work1/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /work1/

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, Internal Server Error. Error.log appache:C:/UwAmp/www/work1/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: That means you haven't enabled `mod_rewrite` in Apache config. Make sure to enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf`.